# Are my classifications of the types of words here correct between the verbs and adjectives connected to miss/missing/missed?

Tags: verbs, adjectives

In the following sentences are my classifications of the type of word connected to "to miss" correct?

> He has been missing for 2 weeks (or "he is still missing")--> "missing" is an adjective

> He missed the bus--> "missed" is the past of the verb "to miss"

> I'm sad that you left our team, you are really missed by everyone--> "missed" is an adjective

Comment: It depends on which linguists you consult. For me: has been missing is a verb.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the 1st and the 2nd, but can add that "missed" in the 3rd is a Past Participle functioning as and adjective. Depending on the grammar/classification you try to map this to, the answer might vary.